# Q: How to map DataTable to DTO not using auto mapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method which returns Data table :

```
public RetirementDiskSettingDto GetRetirementDiskSettingDetails(Guid retirementDiskSettingGuid)
        {
            RetirementDiskSettingDto settingDto = new RetirementDiskSettingDto();
            var details = Provider.GetDataTable(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}RetirementDiskSettingDetails WHERE RetirementDiskSettingGuid = @RetirementDiskSettingGuid ORDER BY [Index]", Provider.DBPrefix), "@RetirementDiskSettingGuid", retirementDiskSettingGuid);
            details.Columns.Add("ColumnTitle");

            DataTable dynamicReportHybridColumns = new BizClasses.DynamicReportHybridColumn().GetHybridColumns();

            DiskSettingColumnType diskSettingColumnType;
            foreach (DataRow row in details.Rows)
            {
                Enum.TryParse(Helper.GetString(row["ColumnType"]), out diskSettingColumnType);

                switch (diskSettingColumnType)
                {
                    case DiskSettingColumnType.HybridColumn:
                        row["ColumnTitle"] = dynamicReportHybridColumns.Select(String.Format("[Guid] = '{0}'", Helper.GetString(row["ColumnName"])))[0]["DisplayTitle"];
                        break;

                    default:
                        row["ColumnTitle"] = Language.GetString(Helper.GetString(row["ColumnName"]), SoftwareManager.Guid);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return settingDto;
        }
```

on the other hand I have a DTO:

```
   public class RetirementDiskSettingDto
     {
        public List<string> SettingTitles { get; set; }  
     }
```

How to map a special column of DataTable (`row["ColumnName"]`) to DTo?
without using auto mapper.

Comment: You could do it by hand, or use a different library in place of automapper. What have you tried?

Comment: @ADyson I've tried do it by hand but not succeeded! Would you give me a hint to do this correctly?

Comment: Well firstly please show what you tried then we can get an idea exactly where you're struggling

Comment: To do it by hand, Could we say let's define an instance of **RetirementDiskSettingDto** and then `instance.SettingTitles = new List<string>()`. Finally, `inputColumn.ForEach(x => { instance.SettingTitles.add(x.ToString())})`.